# Why lex invokes yyerror while parsing comma separated values?

Tags: c, yacc, lex, c89

I am preparing a yacc/lex test program. The lexer is intended to read integer numbers (long), float numbers (double) and date times in a specific format(YYYYMMDD HHMM).

**lexer.l**

```
%{
#include <time.h>
#include "grammar.h"

void read_float_number(void);
void read_integer_number(void);
void read_date_YYYYMMDD_HHMM(void);
void yyerror(const char* msg);

%}

%%

                                                                        /* SKIP BLANKS AND TABS */
[\t ]                                                                   { ; }

                                                                        /* YYYYMMDD HHMM DATE */
[12][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][ ][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]           { read_date_YYYYMMDD_HHMM(); return DATETIME; }

                                                                        /* FLOAT NUMBER */
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+                                                          { read_float_number(); return FLOAT_NUMBER; }

                                                                        /* INTEGER NUMBER */
[0-9]+                                                                  { read_integer_number(); return INTEGER_NUMBER; }

%%

/* READ FLOAT NUMBER */
void read_float_number(void) {
        sscanf(yytext, "%lf", &yylval.float_number);
}

/* READ INTEGER NUMBER */
void read_integer_number(void) {
        sscanf(yytext, "%ld", &yylval.integer_number);
}

/* READ YYYYMMDD HHMM DATE */
void read_date_YYYYMMDD_HHMM(void) {

        /*  DATETIME STRUCT TM */
        struct tm dt;
        char buffer[80];

        /* READ VALUES */
        sscanf(yytext, "%4d%2d%2d %2d%2d", &dt.tm_year, &dt.tm_mon, &dt.tm_mday, &dt.tm_hour, &dt.tm_min);

        /* NORMALIZE VALUES */
        dt.tm_year = dt.tm_year - 1900;         /* NORMALIZE YEAR */
        dt.tm_mon = dt.tm_mon - 1;              /* NORMALIZE MONTH */
        dt.tm_isdst = -1;                       /* NO INFORMATION ABOUT DST */
        mktime(&dt);                            /* NORMALIZE STRUCT TM */

        /* PRINT DATETIME */
        strftime(buffer, 80, "%c %z %Z\n", &dt);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        /* COPY STRUCT TM TO YACC RETURN VALUE */
        memcpy(&dt, &yylval.datetime, sizeof(dt));

}

/* YYERROR */
void yyerror(const char* msg) {
        fprintf(stderr, "yyerror %s\n", msg);
        exit(1);
}
```

**grammar.y**

The grammar is intended to parse this kind of lines (DATETIME,FLOAT,FLOAT,INTEGER):

```
20191201 17000,1.102290,1.102470,0
```

```
%{

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

%}

%union {

        struct tm       datetime;               /* DATE TIME VALUES */
        double          float_number;           /* 8 BYTES DOUBLE VALUE */
        long            integer_number;         /* 8 BYTES INTEGER VALUE */

}

%token  <datetime>              DATETIME
%token  <float_number>          FLOAT_NUMBER
%token  <integer_number>        INTEGER_NUMBER

%%

lastbid_lastask:        DATETIME ',' FLOAT_NUMBER ',' FLOAT_NUMBER ',' INTEGER_NUMBER   { printf("MATCH %lf %lf %ld\n", $3, $5, $7); }
                        ;

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        yyparse();

        return 0;

}
```

The **makefile** to build everything is as follows:

```
CCFLAGS = -std=c89 -c
YFLAGS = -d     # Forces generation of y.tab.h
OBJS = lexer.o grammar.o
TARGET = readfile

readfile:               $(OBJS)
                        cc $(OBJS) -std=c89 -ll -o $(TARGET)

grammar.h grammar.o:    grammar.y
                        yacc $(YFLAGS) -ogrammar.c grammar.y
                        cc $(CCFLAGS) grammar.c

lexer.o:                lexer.l grammar.h
                        lex -olexer.c lexer.l
                        cc $(CCFLAGS) lexer.c

clean:
                        rm -f $(OBJS) grammar.[ch] lexer.c
```

I run readfile but after parsing the DATETIME lex seems to invoke yyerror:

```
% ./readfile 
20191201 170003296,1.102290,1.102470,0
Mon Feb 17 22:20:00 2020 +0100 CET

yyerror syntax error
```

Same for numbers:

```
% ./readfile
45.45
yyerror syntax error
% ./readfile
45
yyerror syntax error
```

But not for arbitrary text:

```
% ./readfile
abc
abc
```

**Why is lex invoking yyerror? What is missing in the lex parsing code?**

Comment: Lex does not invoke yyerror, ever (unless you put an explicit call in an action). Only the parser calls `yyerror` (so it makes more sense to put the definition in your `.y` file).

Comment: I suppose the missing prototype warning when you compile `grammar.c` is suppressed by `-std=c89`. That shouldn't be necessary; aside from antediluvian versions, flex and bison produce modern C code, even on FreeBSD.

Comment: I am not sure if shipped FreeBSD yacc is actually bison. Reading the man page I think it is not, it seems to be Berkeley Yacc, as it describes some potential differences with Bison. Lex seems to be flex in FreeBSD according to the manual.

Comment: Indeed, FreeBSD uses a derivative of Berkeley YACC, originally written by Robert Corbett and currently maintained by Thomas Dickey. But the code it generates should compile without warnings with a C99 compiler (or even a C11 compiler), although it's designed to be compatible with C89.

Comment: The only reason for using -std=c89 is that I am currently rereading "The UNIX programming environment" and "The C Programming Language" and "Yacc and Lex -O'Reilly-"

Comment: @rici you are one of the few persons with hands-on knowledge on yacc here, if you feel like helping today please have a look to my last post, I am stuck on how to handle EOF

Comment: I just answered that question, but I don't really understand why you need to respond to EOF.

Comment: W.r.t. compiler flags, you'd be a lot better off using `-Wall` :-) Any yacc-derivative worth using should produce warning-free code.

Comment: The reason to handle CONTROL+D is that if I do:  `cat test.csv | ./readfile` where test.csv is a bunch of valid lines, I get all lines parsed but the program does not terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your lexer never returns a `','` token. By default, (f)lex scanners print unrecognised characters to stdout, as, for example, in your test with input `abc`.  However, the unrecognised comma is not shown in your output because the `stdout` buffer was not flushed before `exit()` was called in `yyerror()`.

In any event, we usually put a fallback rule as the last rule in the scanner specification:

```
.    { return yytext[0]; }
```

That guarantees that any unrecognised character will be passed through to the parser as a quoted single-character token. If the parser does not expect that token, it will raise a syntax error immediately.

Comment: I still have an issue while reading two lines instead of ones. As it is a different issue I will ask it in another question to avoid messing up with the original question.